# Google Sheets: How to Convert Column Values In mmm:ss or mm:ss Format to Minutes

Tags: google-sheets, time, timestamp, seconds, minute

I currently have a "minutes" column that has values which look like 129:31 or 22:56

The numbers to the left of : are minutes and the numbers to the right of : are seconds.  In Google Sheets, how do I take that column of values and convert it to total number of minutes instead?

For example 129:31 would become 129.52 minutes and 22:56 would become 22.93 minutes.  The reason I need to do this is because I want to use my new column in a SUMIF statement.

I've tried format mm:ss but it doesn't return numbers that I can sum.

Comment: In your situation, are the cell values of `129:31` and `22:56` the date object or the text? And, do you want to overwrite the cells of `129:31` and `22:56` with the number values of `129.52` and `22.93`, respectively?

Comment: they are the text (not  a date object); I don't want to overwrite those cells ... create a new column with 129.52 and 22.93 instead.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood yor expected result, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your following reply,

> they are the text (not a date object); I don't want to overwrite those cells ... create a new column with 129.52 and 22.93 instead.

how about the following sample formula?

```
=BYROW(A1:A,LAMBDA(range,IFERROR(LET(res_1,SPLIT(range,":"),res_2,INDEX(res_1,1,1),res_3,INDEX(res_1,1,2)/60,res_1 + res_3))))
```

[image]

- In this sample formula, the text `129:31` is split by `:` and `31` is divided by `60`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `TIMEVALUE` which takes a string and converts it to a number (you can format it as a number or as date, if you want). Since the input of TIMEVALUE is a string with hours, I suggest you just add a `0:` to add the "hours":

```
=TIMEVALUE("0:"&A1)
```

Just to show you that now you have a correct date format, I summed in the screenshot both values you provided

[image]

If you just want the number exactly as you requested, multiply it by 24 for hours and 60 for minutes

Comment: apologies I should have been clearer.  The column of values currently in the cell look like this '121:41 

As such, when I apply your formula to the cell it returns 0.08450231481   Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Comment: Iit was clear! The solution I suggested let you keep working into a date format, then allowing you to convert it to hours or even days when adding up. As I stated at the end of the post, you just need to multiply by 24 and 60 to get the number exactly as you requested